# Is it possible to add Button<Text> to Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Normally, adding two Text views will produce a single Text view retaining the properties of each individual Text view. For example:

```swift
Text(“Hello ”) + Text(“world!”).foregroundColor(.blue)
```

This should produce `Hello world!`, with `world!` in blue. Now, what should I do if I want `world!` to be tappable and act as a button? Well, logically it would make sense to do this:

```swift
Text(“Hello ”) + Button(action: {}) { Text(“world!”).foregroundColor(.blue) }
```

However, the code directly above does not compile. Is it possible to create Text views with tappable portions as described? My use cas is for Tweets with `@` mentions or `#` hashtags where you would tap on either the mention or the hashtag to be shown a detail view.

**EDIT:** The reason why using a Text view and a Button in an HStack is unsuitable is because this is within a function which returns a Text view for the content of a tweet:

```
func styledText(text: String) -> Text {
    var output = Text("")
    let components = text.tokenize("@#. ")
    for component in components {
        if component.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "@#")) != nil {
            output = output + Text(component).foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        } else {
            output = output + Text(component)
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

Where `String.tokenize` is the following:

```swift
extension String {
    func tokenize(_ delimiters: String) -> [String] {
        var output = [String]()
        var buffer = ""
        for char in self {
            if delimiters.contains(char) {
                output.append(buffer)
                buffer = String(char)
            } else {
                buffer += String(char)
            }
        }
        output.append(buffer)
        return output
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** If it helps, I'm trying to create a SwiftUI version of this: https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you want this or you want explicitly to use + but your goal you can reach by this

```
 HStack {
                Text("Hello ")
                Button(action: {
                    // do something
                    print("tapped")
                }, label: {
                    Text("world!").foregroundColor(.blue)
                })
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response — this isn't suitable, as the `@` mention or `#` hashtag button would be in a body of text, more than a single line in height, and could be anywhere in said text.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the AnyView to get what you need. If you are VERY good at programming, you can introduce more complicated auto layout for your goal.

```
extension AnyView{
    static func + (left: AnyView, right: AnyView) -> AnyView{
        return AnyView(HStack{left.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                              right.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)})
    }
}


func styledText(text: String) -> AnyView {
    var output = AnyView(Text(""))
    let components = text.tokenize("@#. ")
    for component in components {
        if component.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "@#")) != nil {
            output = output + AnyView(Text(component).foregroundColor(.accentColor).onTapGesture {
                print(component)
            })
        } else {
            output = output + AnyView(Text(component))
        }
    }

    return output
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If you make the spacing of the `HStack` in the `AnyView` extension equal to `0`,  it almost produces the desired result! The only issue is that the `HStack` doesn't wrap it's contents, so the entire paragraph of text will end up on one line, messing up the view. Is there any way to overcome this or make it happen?

Comment: So you need the fixSize to test different configurations

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, however this is only really useful for link-type styles. In other words, I don't think there's an easy solution to do any custom action if so desired.

My solution proposes to create a `UIViewRepresentable` that can display an attributed string:

```swift
struct AttributedText: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.attributedText = self.attributedString
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {}
    
}
```

you could then create an Attributed String like so:

```swift
var attributedString: NSAttributedString = {
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello, ")
    let blueWorld = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "world!")
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any ] = [
        .link: NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com")!
    ]
    let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: blueWorld.length)
    blueWorld.setAttributes(attributes, range: fullRange)
    attrString.append(blueWorld)
    return attrString
}()
```

or use any good library until there is a better option from apple for this. This allows you to simply display the text as it was a regular `Text`:

```swift
struct MyText {

    var body: some View {
        AttributedText(attributedString: myCustomAttributedString)
    }

}
```

This solution has potential when you're only interested in links and are okay with the default display of them (as far as I can tell, you can't change this).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Button to Text elements to be part of a single clickable area, you can nest them within a single Button like this

```
                Button(action: {
                    // Your action here
                    print("Combined button clicked")
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Don't have an account?")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))

                        Text("Sign up")
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                    }
                }//SignUp
```

This way, clicking either "Don't have an account?" or "Sign up" will trigger the same action because they are part of the same button.